# Как останавливать блок при скролле, когда он достиг другого блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

У меня есть блок (1), который в определенный момент становится fixed и прилипает к верху страницы.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bo = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ( bo > 300 ) {
            $('.akcii').addClass('fixedblock');
            $('.left_side').addClass('fixedblockLeftSide');
            $('.content_catalog').addClass('fixedblockContent');
        }
        else {
            $('.akcii').removeClass('fixedblock');
            $('.left_side').removeClass('fixedblockLeftSide');
            $('.content_catalog').removeClass('fixedblockContent');
        }
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако, по достижении блока "недавно просмотренные товары" (2) от должен останавливаться. Трудность еще в том, что блок (3) реализован с догрузкой товаров, поэтому просто посчитать длину всей страницы и вычесть блок (2) не получается

Answer (score 0):

Извините, может, я не правильно понял суть вопроса, но зачем просчитывать длинну всей страницы?
У меня была похожая задача. Я вычислял высоту блока (1), и складывал ее с $(window).scrollTop(). После чего вычислял отступ блока (2) от начала страницы. Потом я отнимал сумму от оступа для блока (2) - получал число, на которое нужно сдвинуть вверх блок (1)
Для примера:

```
var topShift = 0;
var shift = divShift - sum;
if(shift< 0) {
  topShift = shift;
}
```

Опять же, если я правильно понял вашу проблему.

Comment: Опять же могу быть не прав, но в подобных случаях (если вам нужно прилепить шапку), делается это следующим способом: (как минимум других я не знаю) делаются 2 одинаковых контейнера(Хидера), один распологается на странице, как обычно, а второму придают fixed значение, причем второй скрывают (display: none) до определенного моммента. Такой способ я использовал тогда, когда нужно было с определенного момента (скролла до определенной линии), хидер прилепал к верхнему краю браузера.
Но я до конца не понимаю, что вы хотите реализовать, поэтому этот способ может вам не подойти.

Comment: не понятно в первом вашем способе как мне вычислить отступ блока (2) от начала страницы, если у меня происходит догрузка контента и соответственно увеличивается отступ от начала страницы

Comment: @Jussia вы можеже воспользоваться:


**var offsetTop = Element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop;** либо **$("div.content").offset()**

Comment: @Jussia, Если Вам все еще непонятно, скажите, я добавлю кусочек кода в ответ выше.

Comment: $("div.content").offset() возвращает undefined, а var offsetTop = Element.getBoundingClientRect().top + document.body.scrollTop возвращает, что getBoundingClientRect() is not a function.

Добавьте пожалуйста в код, потому что не совсем понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Советую попробовать сделать при помощи jquery-viewport-checker

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.example').viewportChecker({
        /* body */
    });
});
```

body выполнится когда .example появится в зоне видимости.

Comment: мне это не подойдет, т. к. в body я могу передавать только определенные значения типа classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
        offset: 100 и только для $('.example'). Мне же нужно, чтобы (1) останавливался, когда доходит до (2)